# How to filter Integer fields by string values in kendo grid?

Tags: c#, angular, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-angular2

In Kendo grid, I would like to filter int fields by string values.

But ToDataSourceResult throw exception

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Method 'System.String ToLower()' declared on type 'System.String' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Int64''
```

For Example :

```
public class BatchDetail
{
     public long TrackNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I want to find all track numbers that contain "5"

Comment: filtering int fields by string values -> can you provide an example...

Comment: I have stored a numeric value in the database like 1000 when the user filters the number 1 I need to find all the items that contain the number 1